# write a complete program that will read 3 NUMBers from user and calculates and displays the product only of the positive integers

Tags: c++

This is what I've tried so far

```
// Calculate the product of three integers 
#include <iostream> // allows program to perform input and output

using namespace std;

// function main begins program execution 
int main()
{
    int x; // first integer to multiply 
    int y; // second integer to multiply 
    int z; // third integer to multiply 
    int result; // the product of the three integers 
    cout << "Enter three integers: "; // prompt user for data 
    cin >> x >> y >> z; 
    result = x * y * z; 
}
```

what can i do to solve this question?

Comment: `result = (x > 0 ? x : 1) * (y > 0 ? : y : 1) * (z > 0 ? z : 1);`

Comment: Umm hmm I would not use a ternary operator for a beginner....

Comment: Please don't include line-numbers in the [mcve] you show, if you need to point to a specific line add a *comment* on that line. And please make sure it's also complete. And replicates your problem. And doesn't contain other unrelated problems (especially simple ones like build errors).

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). LAstly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them, like for example ask a question in the question itself (the title should only be a short summary of the problem you have).

Comment: "write a complete program that will read 3 NUMBers from user and calculates and displays the product only of the positive integers" - Ehh, no. How about *you* do that. This is not a free code-writing or do-my-homework service.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
If you do not need it to loop use a if instead of a while.

Looks like you need to study some conditional statements try:

```
result = x*y*z;
while(result < 0){
   cout << "Enter three integers: "; // prompt user for data 
   cin >> x >> y >> z; 
}
cout << result << endl;
```

Should work fine...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a condition to check the number at the input itself:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int inum1 = 0;
    std::cin >> inum1;
    if (inum1 < 0) { inum1 = 1; }
    int inum2 = 0;
    std::cin >> inum2;
    if (inum2 < 0) { inum2 = 1; }
    int inum3 = 0;
    std::cin >> inum3;
    if (inum3 < 0) { inum3 = 1; }
    std::cout << inum1*inum2*inum3 << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Notice that in my example I have used std::cout and std::cin instead of `using namespace std`

use of `using namespace std` is fine if you're a beginner or the program is small, but is discouraged for large programs :)

If you find typing `std::` tedious, you can instead include the following statements:

```
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
```

---

Also, `printf` and `scanf` is usually preferred over `cin` and `cout` for fast I/O.